# Where is the solution's webPart I have published on my sharepoint site?

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-online, visual-studio

I work on SharePoint 2013 and with Visual Studio 2013, I have published a SharePoint solution on my SharePoint Site. But in this solution I have created a Web Part in C# and I haven't found this in my Site.There is someone who know a way to get this Web Part on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is in a Feature. When the Feature is activated, the Webpart is installed in the current site´s Gallery and therefore available to insert it into any webpartzone

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Visual Studio Solution Explorer window
2. Expand Features folder
3. Double click on each feature and find which feature is associated with your web part
4. Now open the site in browser
5. Open Site Settings -> Site Collection Settings
6. Look from the feature you find in Step #3
7. If it is Activated, then first DeActivate and then Activate

Now you can edit page and add web part.